# how to attach both rotate and tap event listeners to shapes in konvajs?

Tags: konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I was working on including rotate gestures in my app following the tutorial given on https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Gestures.html. But in my app i have also attached 'tap' event listener so whenever I tried to rotate the shape using gesture , 'tap' event gets emitted also and on taping the shape for once 'tap' event is getting emitted twice.
Is there any way so that I can prevent that from happening means while rotation via 2 finger rotate gesture, 'tap' event should not get emitted?
is there any way to use stopImmediatePropagation() in konvajs?

```
  group.on('tap', function(ev) {
    console.log("tap event")
  });

  group.on('rotatestart', function(ev) {
    oldRotation = ev.evt.gesture.rotation;
    startScale = rect.scaleX();
    group.stopDrag();
    group.draggable(false);
    text.text('rotating...');
  });

  group.on('rotate', function(ev) {
    var delta = oldRotation - ev.evt.gesture.rotation;
    group.rotate(-delta);
    oldRotation = ev.evt.gesture.rotation;
    group.scaleX(startScale * ev.evt.gesture.scale);
    group.scaleY(startScale * ev.evt.gesture.scale);
    layer.batchDraw();
  });

  group.on('rotateend rotatecancel', function(ev) {
    text.text(defaultText);
    group.draggable(true);
    layer.batchDraw();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pudio/z68nc5p3/2/

Comment: I concur that tap generates 2 events in your sample fiddle. Also that the demo on the landing page of hammer.js provides for tap and rotate though not with canvas or Konvajs.

Answer (score 1):

`tap` event is "native" konva event. It means `Konva` supports it by default. So `Konva` knows nothing about rotate events. Even if you are rotation a shape, for konva it still looks like you are tapping on it (it has `touchdown` and `touchmove` events).

But hammerjs handle such situations automatically. So instead of listening events on Konva node, you can listen to them on Hammertime instance:

```js
hammertime.on('tap', function(ev) {
  console.log("tap event")
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hj84aLys/

That also will partially fix the double `tap` trigger issue, mentioned in the comments.

Another workaround is just check in `tap` event if rotate is happened resently. If it is not - then you can continue:

```
var rotated = false;
group.on('touchstart', function(ev) {
  rotated = false;
});

group.on('rotate', function(ev) {
  rotated = true;
});

group.on('tap', function(ev) {
  // do nothing on rotate.
  if (rotated) {
     return;
  }
  console.log("tap event")
});
```

Comment: In the description of the demo at https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Gestures.html you mention that you used a modified version of hammer.js - is that still true ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat yes. Originally, it works on DOM nodes. Not Konva nodes.